# Running a Solaris binary on SPARC without SPARC hardware

Tags: solaris, emulation, sparc

I have a historical binary ObjectGeode which is only able to work on SUN SPARC machine with Solaris OS (doesn't matter which Solaris version). My questions are:

- How can I run the program without Sun-SPARC hardware?
- If emulation is the only option, which tool is appropriate for this issue?

I would prefer Linux or Windows as host system.

**Edit:**
I installed qemu- 2.5.50  32bit.However I can't launch the image- ***Solaris_2.6_Software_05_98.img***
I used Cygwin in order to invoke command.Here it is

*./qemu-system-sparc.exe -L . -hda Solaris_2.6_Software_05_98.img -m 256*

But I got no response.
It looks something is missing.Is there a guidance for windows launching qemu?

Comment: If you search for "solaris_2.6_software_05_98.img" using your favourite search engine, you'll find detailed installation instructions. You need a firmware image in addition to the installation CD image you have, and you need to create a destination disk image (which is used for `-hda`; the CD image is specified using `-cdrom`).

Comment: Perhaps using a cloud service instead of emulation?  Have a look here: https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-cloud-providers-providing-solaris-on-SPARC. Probably somewhat outdated answers, but still.

Comment: I thought there were a few other providers not mentioned in the link above.  Some universities use SPARC equipment in their CS labs and you might be able to get access?
If this is for a business need, you might be able to buy an older SPARC workstation to do whatever you need done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have a SPARC system, emulation is the only option.

[QEMU can emulate SPARCstations](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/SPARC), running Solaris up to version 9. Solaris 10 doesn't support 32-bit platforms so it can't run on the `sun4m` emulation; I get the impression it's still broken on the `sun4u` emulation (which is still beta anyway).

You can run QEMU on many different platforms, including most Linux distributions and Windows.